# Putting wrapfigure right next to the following paragraph

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, pandoc

I'd like to put a floating picture to the right of not just any text, but specifically the text that follows. The problem is that `wrapfigure` seems to choose a subsequent paragraph.

In the following Pandoc example, I would like the picture to be right next to the *Occupation* / *Drive* / *Pillars of Sanity* section; instead, it shows up next to the *After seeing Europe...* part.

```
---
header-includes:
    \usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
---

# Clarence Merriweather

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{portrait.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

* Occupation: Professor
* Drive: Scholarship
* Pillars of Sanity:
  * Positivism: the world can be understood via science
  * Enlightenment will prevail over primitive barbarism
  * The world changes, but I'll always have the family house in Abingdon


After seeing Europe sink into the death cult that was the Great War,
Prof. Merriweather, himself spared of experiencing combat first-hand
by his academic standing and his asthma, decided to leave his faculty
position in Oxford to pursue a new career in NYU. 

His interest in primitive cultures and the occult is purely
academical. He is happy to lend his expertise to the FBI to help with
cases involving "crazies who imitate the primitive savages".
```

[image: Typeset output]

How can I force `wrapfigure` to put things on the current paragraph, i.e. next to the "Occupation", "Drive" and "Pillars" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly happens between the markdown(?) of pandoc and the LaTeX input, but wrapfigure resists being placed in a list. The answer to starting "immediately" is

```
\indent \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}\par
```

before the beginning of the list.

Also, there is a white-space border above the content of wrapfigure, so it doesn't touch the text above. To make the image start right on that line you should undo the border inside the wrapfigure. In total (actually, in "partial")

```
# Clarence Merriweather

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\intextsep}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{portrait.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

\indent \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}\par
* Occupation: Professor
* Drive: Scholarship
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with pandoc, but in LaTeX code (resulted from pandoc) code should be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section*{Clarence Merriweather} % this is LaTeX emulation of pandoc
    \begin{itemize}
\item Occupation: Professor
\item Drive: Scholarship
\item Pillars of Sanity:
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Positivism: the world can be understood via science
  \item Enlightenment will prevail over primitive barbarism
  \item The world changes, but I'll always have the family house in Abingdon
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth} % <--- had to be inserted here
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[height=\linewidth, % in real document remove this option
                 width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{portrait.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
After seeing Europe sink into the death cult that was the Great War,
Prof. Merriweather, himself spared of experiencing combat first-hand
by his academic standing and his asthma, decided to leave his faculty
position in Oxford to pursue a new career in NYU.

His interest in primitive cultures and the occult is purely
academical. He is happy to lend his expertise to the FBI to help with
cases involving ''crazies who imitate the primitive savages''.
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

As you can observe, `wrapfigure` had to be at begin of paragraph, where is desired that image be inserted.

**Addendum:**

Unfortunately wrapfig doesn't work with itemize. A possible solution is incapsulate lists in `minipage` and instead of `wrapfigure` use `\InsertBoxR` defined in plain TeX macro package `insbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\input{insbox}%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TeX macro, very useful


\begin{document}

\section*{Clarence Merriweather}

   \InsertBoxR{0}{%
    \includegraphics[height=0.4\linewidth, % in real document remove this option
                     width =0.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{portrait.jpg}
                  }   
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt, itemsep=0.2ex, leftmargin=*}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Occupation: Professor
\item Drive: Scholarship
\item Pillars of Sanity:
        \begin{itemize}
    \item Positivism: the world can be understood via science
    \item Enlightenment will prevail over primitive barbarism
    \item The world changes, but I'll always have the family house in Abingdon
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    
After seeing Europe sink into the death cult that was the Great War,
Prof. Merriweather, himself spared of experiencing combat first-hand
by his academic standing and his asthma, decided to leave his faculty
position in Oxford to pursue a new career in NYU.

His interest in primitive cultures and the occult is purely
academical. He is happy to lend his expertise to the FBI to help with
cases involving ''crazies who imitate the primitive savages''.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the picture to be next to the `itemize` right after the `section*`.

Comment: Unfortunately wrapfig doesn't work with itemize. See its documentation for details.

Comment: @Cactus, one work around is incapsulate lists in `minipage` and for inserting figure use  `\InsertBoxR` defined in the plain TeX macro package insbox. See addendum to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have grown increasingly fond of replacing wrapfig with paracol.  It is far more robust, but it does require manually breaking paragraphs (`\nopar` and `\noindent`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\nopar}{{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Clarence Merriweather}

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.7\textwidth-\columnsep}% right column is 0.3\textwidth
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Occupation: Professor
\item Drive: Scholarship
\item Pillars of Sanity:
        \begin{itemize}
    \item Positivism: the world can be understood via science
    \item Enlightenment will prevail over primitive barbarism
    \item The world changes, but I'll always have the family house in Abingdon
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

After seeing Europe sink into the death cult that was the Great War,
Prof. Merriweather, himself spared of experiencing combat first-hand
by his academic\nopar
\switchcolumn
\includegraphics[height=2.5in, % in real document remove this option
                 width=\linewidth]{example-image}%{portrait.jpg}
\end{paracol}
\noindent standing and his asthma, decided to leave his faculty
position in Oxford to pursue a new career in NYU

His interest in primitive cultures and the occult is purely
academical. He is happy to lend his expertise to the FBI to help with
cases involving ''crazies who imitate the primitive savages''.
\end{document}
```