# the second wrapfigure won't wrap

Tags: floats

My problem is that when I use 2 wrapfigures, the second one always stays below any text and on the left side.

---

edit: if i follow gernot’s [advice](https://texwelt.de/fragen/20778/verstandnisproblem-mit-wrapfigure) it works, but why does `\section{}` or
`\paragraph{}` not count as seperate Paragraph for wrapfigure?

---

[image: example code]

example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \rule{0.9\linewidth}{0.75\linewidth}
    \label{fig:myfig1}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \rule{0.9\linewidth}{0.75\linewidth}
    \label{fig:myfig2}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can have only one wrap-figure per paragraph. Either you can add a paragraph, you need the 'invisible paragraph' trick from https://texwelt.de/fragen/20778/verstandnisproblem-mit-wrapfigure

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574675/putting-wrapfigure-right-next-to-the-following-paragraph/574735?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.0915#574735